# Deactivate plugins only for mobile devices

Tags: plugins, mobile

I tried to use [`deactivate_plugins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/deactivate_plugins/) function to deactivate a plugin only for mobile devices.

It worked: when I enter site on mobile phone the plugin is deactivated, but when I enter site on PC the plugin is deactivated too.

Is there a way to not *deactivate* a plugin, but only *disable* it for mobiles?

```
function deactivate_plugin_conditional() {
  if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    deactivate_plugins( array('/first-plugin/first.php', '/second-plugin/second.php') );    
  }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'deactivate_plugin_conditional' );
```

Comment: Plugins run on the server itself, not on the browser. If you  deactivate a plugin, then that deactivates it, period. It turns it off. You shouldn't be turning off a plugin just because somebody visited the site from a mobile device.

Comment: Yea but i have a plugin that mess up all the mobile theme but it's working on pc. So i was thinking about disable it on mobiles only. So there is no way to do it so ?

Comment: Although you cannot deactivate plugin for browser/client specific but you can modify the plugin behavior for clients. You will need to find the root of the error of your problem. It could be a JS or CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you deactivate a plugin, the change is stored in database, so in all subsequent access the plugin is deactivated, no matter the device used to access the site.

### Filtering the option

Active plugin in WordPress are retrieved using [**`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins/) function.

It uses the option `"active_plugins"` to get the currently active plugin. All options in WordPress can be filtered using the [`"option_{$option}"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/) filter hook, that in this case is `"option_active_plugins"`.

### Acting early

You may think to use a plugin to filter that option, but the problem is that is possible that the plugins(s) you want to exclude are loaded before your plugin, because you can't never be sure you plugin is loaded for first.

The solution is to use a [MU plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) for the scope.

### Too early issue

MU plugins run very early in WordPress, that gives you the possibity to filter the `"option_active_plugins"` option.

Another issue is that MU plugins load very early, even before the file [`wp-includes/vars.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/vars.php) that contain the function `wp_is_mobile()` is loaded, so if you use that function inside a MU plugin you get a fatal error.

Load the file "manually" is **not** an option, because WordPress will load that file using `require` and not `require_once`, so if you load the file, when WordPress load it again you get a fatal error for function already defined.

The only solution is write *again* `wp_is_mobile()`, just coping from core and using a different name.

### Let's code

Create PHP file and save in `wp-content/mu-plugins` folder.

First of all write there a function that returns all the plugin you want to disable for mobile devices:

```
function my_non_mobile_plugins() {
  return array(

    // an array of all the plugins you want to exclude for mobile

    'plugin-folder/plugin-file.php',
    'another-plugin-folder/another-plugin-file.php',
    'no-folder-plugin-file.php'

  );
}
```

After that write a *clone* of `wp_is_mobile()` function, with another name:

```
function my_is_mobile() { 
  $is_mobile = false;
  if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== false
  ) {
    $is_mobile = true;
  }
  return $is_mobile;
}
```

Finally, filter `'option_active_plugins'` making use of previous function to check if remove plugins or not

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'my_disable_plugins_for_mobiles' );

function my_disable_plugins_for_mobiles( $plugins ) {

  if ( ! my_is_mobile() ) {
    return $plugins; // for non-mobile device do nothing
  }

  $not_allowed = my_non_mobile_plugins(); // get non allowed plugins

  return array_values( array_diff( $plugins, $not_allowed ) );

}
```

Comment: It don't matter what the file name will be ? Or it have to be something like load.php ?

I want to thank You very much worked like a charm. Thank You for step by step explanation of code writing, It helped a lot.

Comment: No, file name is not important because WP loads all the MU plugins no matter the name. I suggest to not use too generic name like `load.php` and use instead more *explicit* name like `no-mobile-plugins.php` in this way it is immediately clear what that file does. E.g. Someone else may need to access to your files or the *future you* may forget what that `load.php` does... @c64girl

Comment: Ok if i can change it i will change it to no-mobile-plugins :) Thats why i was asking about the file name :) Thank You again for Your help. And explaining step by step thro the code.

Answer (score -2):

The way I did it was to simply hide the plugin bits (this works if the plugin is used to display extra information, for instance social media tabs).

I simply looked with the Developer Tool in Chrome to see which was the div I wanted to hide, then in my own CSS I added a rule like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   div#nameOfDiv {
       display: none;
   }
}
```