# problem disabling plugin only for mobile

Tags: plugins, mobile

I am trying to enable a plugin only for mobile and I have consulted this thread:
[Deactivate plugins only for mobile devices](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165796/deactivate-plugins-only-for-mobile-devices)

I have made some changes to the last function as I want to enable only for mobile, while the thread suggest how to disable to mobile.

I don't know how specify the plugin that I want to specify, so I include 2 files. This is in a folder in my wp-content/ plugins/name-of-plugin, where there are an index.php file and a name-of-plugin.php file.

This is my code, saved in a my-code.php file, places on mu-plugins of wordpress. Unfrotunately,  it doesn't work. Any help how to fix this?

```
 <?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: My mobile enabler
 */

function my_non_mobile_plugins() {
  return array(

    // i am not sure how specifiy the plugin I want to disable. I have added these two lines

    '/name-of-folder-plugin/plugin-name.php',
    '/name-of-folder-plugin/index.php'
  );
}

function my_is_mobile() { 
  $is_mobile = false;
  if ( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mobile') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Silk/') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Kindle') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'BlackBerry') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mini') !== false
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Opera Mobi') !== false
  ) {
    $is_mobile = true;
  }
  return $is_mobile;
}


add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'my_disable_plugins_for_mobiles' );

function my_disable_plugins_for_mobiles( $plugins ) {

  if ( ! my_is_mobile() ) {
  $not_allowed = my_non_mobile_plugins(); // get non allowed plugins

  return array_values( array_diff( $plugins, $not_allowed ) );
    
  }

return $plugins; // for mobile device do nothing

}
```

Comment: if it's your plugin then why disable it on mobiles? Just detect if it's a mobile and return early, there's no need to disable the plugin, deactivating a plugin per page load is not a good approach. Especially when you can open a browser sized to behave like a mobile, and you can unfold a mobile to take up a tablet sized UI, detecting mobiles will be unreliable ( and fundamentally incompatible with page caching plugins and CDNs such as cloudflare )

Comment: No this isn't my plugin, so  that's why I want to enable for mobile.

Comment: what problem are you fixing by doing this?